# Any suggestions as to how we could connect the various Neurodiverse Labels (ADHD, Dyslexia, Dyspraxia and Autism) to the Torah?

Tags: choleh-sick, psych-mentalhealth

The website below lists the various challenges and struggles of people with the various neurodiverse labels as well as the struggles it also lists their qualities and their strengths and the various careers associated with each label.

exceptionalindividuals.com/neurodiversity

For example:

Dyspraxia (known as DCD in US)

Leadership
Emphathy
Strategy
Problem Solving

As a someone diagnosed with dyspraxia I have found Sefer Tanya to be very useful, understanding the way my brain works more than any other sefer I have come across (in particular chapters 26 to 28).  If that is the case then there may be lots of other Jews out there diagnosed with dyspraxia or DCD who may be able to benefit from this information.

Does anyonoe have any suggestions as to how we could match up the various neurodiverse labels (ADHD, Dyslexia, Autism and Dyspraxia DCD)  to Torah that may be able to help them? If a genuine pattern was found this could surely be helpful for those seeking their portion in Torah and Avodas Hashem.

Comment: Good question, but I think that diagnosing disorders that have no hilchatic consequences is not common in Gemara. We have חרש, שוטה, אילם, טוטרן, סומא, all of them are discussed in halachic point of view, ad are not linked with classifications as DSM or ICD, that are medical and treatment focused, for health workers

Comment: This might not be a direct answer to your question, but the book "Healthy in Body Mind & Spirit" by the Lubavitcher Rebbe might be a very good starting point: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/2308511/jewish/Healthy-in-Body-Mind-Spirit-Volume-3.htm